# Run vb script on linux box

Tags: linux

This is all new to me to please bear with me!

I have a situation where we have a form on a website which collects data and sends it to a mySQL table on a web server.  That info is sent to a mySQL table on a linux box from the web server, I believe through some kind of import script on the linux box.

Last week our linux server got hung up and now the import scripts aren't working.  I have a import.txt file that I need to restart (I believe) but am not sure how to do it.

I researched on the web but I only see info about .sh files.

Thanks!

Here's what I need to run if that helps:

```
Public Sub ImportPubOrders()
Dim rsCopy1 As Recordset, rsCopy2 As Recordset, rsCopy3 As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String, strCriteria As String, strODBCdate As String
Dim lngFound As Long
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set wrkODBC = CreateWorkspace("ODBCWorkSpace", "pubadmin", "Abo1prA5", dbUseODBC)
Set MySQLConn = wrkODBC.OpenConnection("ODBC;DSN=publications;DESC=MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver DSN;DATABASE=publications;SERVER=10.116.11.2;UID=pubadmin;PASSWORD=Abo1prA5;PORT=3306;OPTION=3;STMT=;")
MySQLConn.QueryTimeout = 180

strODBCdate = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Date), "yyyy-mm-dd")
'strODBCdate = "2009-03-11"

'Copy records from More.net PRO to DBSRVR
Set OAwrkODBC = CreateWorkspace("ODBCWorkSpace", "sslAGOmySQL", "k4-4js94nd", dbUseODBC)
Set OAMySQLConn = OAwrkODBC.OpenConnection("ODBC;DSN=OA_generalPRO;DESC=MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver DSN;DATABASE=www_ago_mo_gov_ssl_data;SERVER=db.kinetic.more.net;UID=sslAGOmySQL;PASSWORD=k4-4js94nd;PORT=3306;OPTION=3;STMT=;")

strSQL = "LOCK TABLE orders_contacts READ, orders_ids READ, orders_items READ, orders_order READ"
OAMySQLConn.Execute (strSQL)

    'Check if there are orders to download
    strCriteria = "DATE_FORMAT(orders_order.order_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = " & Chr(34) & strODBCdate & Chr(34)
    strSQL = "SELECT form_id FROM orders_order WHERE " & strCriteria
    OAMySQLConn.Execute (strSQL)
    lngFound = OAMySQLConn.RecordsAffected

    'Orders have been submitted and need to be downloaded
    If lngFound >= 1 Then
        strSQL = "SELECT form_id, contact_id, DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS order_date FROM orders_order WHERE " & strCriteria
        Set rsCopy1 = OAMySQLConn.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        Do While Not rsCopy1.EOF
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO orders_order (form_id, contact_id, order_date) " & _
                "VALUES (" & rsCopy1!form_id & ", " & rsCopy1!contact_id & ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy1!order_date & Chr(34) & ")"
            MySQLConn.Execute (strSQL)
            rsCopy1.MoveNext
        Loop
        rsCopy1.Close

        strSQL = "SELECT item_id, orders_items.form_id, pub_name, quantity " & _
            "FROM orders_items INNER JOIN orders_order ON orders_items.form_id = orders_order.form_id " & _
            "WHERE " & strCriteria
        Set rsCopy2 = OAMySQLConn.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        Do While Not rsCopy2.EOF
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO orders_items (item_id, form_id, pub_name, quantity) " & _
                "VALUES (" & rsCopy2!item_id & ", " & rsCopy2!form_id & ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy2!pub_name & Chr(34) & ", " & rsCopy2!quantity & ")"
            MySQLConn.Execute (strSQL)
            rsCopy2.MoveNext
        Loop
        rsCopy2.Close

        strSQL = "SELECT orders_contacts.contact_id, orders_contacts.form_id, org_name, first_name, last_name, address1, address2, city, state, " & _
            "zip, email, phone, DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS date_added " & _
            "FROM orders_contacts INNER JOIN orders_order ON orders_contacts.contact_id = orders_order.contact_id " & _
            "WHERE " & strCriteria
        Set rsCopy3 = OAMySQLConn.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        Do While Not rsCopy3.EOF
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO orders_contacts (contact_id, form_id, org_name, first_name, last_name, address1, " & _
                "address2, city, state, zip, email, phone, date_added) " & _
                "VALUES (" & rsCopy3!contact_id & ", " & rsCopy3!form_id & ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!org_name & Chr(34) & _
                ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!first_name & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!last_name & Chr(34) & _
                ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!address1 & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!address2 & Chr(34) & _
                ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!city & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!state & Chr(34) & _
                ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!zip & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!email & Chr(34) & _
                ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!phone & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & rsCopy3!date_added & Chr(34) & ")"
            MySQLConn.Execute (strSQL)
            rsCopy3.MoveNext
        Loop
        rsCopy3.Close

    Else
        DoCmd.Hourglass False
        Dim RS0 As Recordset
        Set RS0 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("log_Errors")
        RS0.AddNew
            RS0("error_loc") = "ZERO publication orders submitted online for " & strODBCdate
            RS0("error_time") = Now()
        RS0.Update
        RS0.Close
        Set RS0 = Nothing
    End If

strSQL = "UNLOCK TABLES"
OAMySQLConn.Execute (strSQL)

DoCmd.Hourglass False

Dim RS10 As Recordset
Set RS10 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("log_Errors")
RS10.AddNew
    RS10("error_loc") = "Import publications completed without error"
    RS10("error_time") = Now()
RS10.Update
RS10.Close
Set RS10 = Nothing

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Dim RS2 As Recordset
    Set RS2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("log_Errors")
    RS2.AddNew
        RS2("error_loc") = "procedure ImportPubOrders"
        RS2("error_num") = Err.Number
        RS2("error_desc") = Err.Description
        RS2("error_time") = Now()
    RS2.Update
    RS2.Close
    Set RS2 = Nothing

Set rsCopy1 = Nothing
Set rsCopy2 = Nothing
Set rsCopy3 = Nothing
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use third party libraries as linux does not support VBScript. And are you sure that it is has the .txt extension? If so what is this about VBScript?

Comment: It's possible that it's VB and not VB Script.  It definitely has a .txt extension so I can't figure out how to run it.  The guy who wrote it left the office.

Answer (score 0):

This is Visual Basic. VBScript does not support the "On Error GoTo [label]" statement.